# controllerAs with directives and isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I want to create a ok / cancel button set where the developer can change the label

I have the following directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myButtons',function(){

    var ctrl = function ($scope) {
        var controller = this;
    };

    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',

        scope: {
            cancelLabel: '@',
            saveLabel: '@',
            save: '&',
            cancel: '&'
        },

        templateUrl: 'directives/myButtons.html',

        controller: ctrl,
        controllerAs: 'controller',
        bindToController: true,
    };
```

});

the html for the directive includes the following

```
<div>
   <button>{{controller.cancelLabel}}</button>
   <button>{{controller.saveLabel}}</button>
</div>
```

the actual html calling this directive is

```
 <my-buttons saveLabel="Discard" cancelLabel="Cancel"></my-buttons>
```

however, the labels are not being set. How can I get the contents of the saveLabel= and cancelLabel= from the html

the form itself is shown, and if I manually set controller.saveLabel = "save" then it appears just fine on the save button

I know I'm missing something very simple ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You directive element attributes are wrong, it should be hyphen(`-`) separated instead of using camel case.

**Markup**

```
<my-buttons save-label="Discard" cancel-label="Cancel"></my-buttons>
```

Comment: aaaaaarrrrrrrrrrghhhhhhhhhhh. I *knew* that. I am an idiot. thanks ;)

Comment: @jmls nothing like that..Glad to help you..Thanks :-)

Comment: heh. I tried already. "you can accept in 9 minutes .." ;) You should also upvote up my question as it is "clear and well-researched". And stupid ... *grin*

Comment: @jmls Anyways..Cheers & Happy Coding :)

Comment: sorry , been up to my eyeballs in stuff - just came back online. thanks for all your help ;)